# Cannot see textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am trying to make a layout with this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_corner_radius"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#f27181"
        android:id="@+id/charity_overview_card"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.sharesmile.share.views.LBTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:text="Women Empowerment"
        android:id="@+id/iv_charity_category_title"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_charity_overview"

        />
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >
        <com.sharesmile.share.views.LBTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_charity_amount"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Test"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

but the last textview is not visible, even in the preview it is not showing, it shows like this :

[image]

As you can see the textview is not visible, i haven't given any weight, still facing this issue.

Also when i increase the size of the textview the value is visible as you can see here :

[image]

Comment: Your CardView is match_parent while the parent is wrap_content, you are supossed to not see anything unless the parent had given space to layout itself and the result you see have the TextView below the visible area, change the cardview to wrap_content also.

Comment: Thank you @MarcosVasconcelos. so silly of me.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos, facing one more issue, when i changed what you suggested, the below textview became visible, but the above textview as you can see has women empowerment text, and only women is visible after the change.

Comment: Well thats something about android:lines and wrap_content, if you layout can't fit the screen you may consider adding it to a ScrollView

Comment: Scrollview is not required here.

Comment: Maybe you missing another wrap_content, also, if you plan to just add the whole view inside of the recyclerview, you better using wrap_content on the root elements also

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout inside other parent LinearLayout with dynamic size will produce this type of issues. You should avoid nesting layout inside layout as much as possibile.

This issue can be simply fixed by removing the parent layout orientation.

For improvement

```
<CardView>
<LinearLayout> vertical

//Add 'N' child items here

</LinearLayout> 
</CardView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the following properties of your main `LinearLayout`, Make height and width to `match_parent`

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```